# Create button onclick event inside javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I know about the way of using html to occur an event when button is clicked

```
<onclick="function()">
```

but I was wondering If i could do this inside javascript so I created an event listener once event happens my function runs but I dont really know why it's not working.

```js
setTimeout(() => {
  alert("hi starquest");
}, 200);

var submit = document.getElementById('submit');
var input1 = document.getElementById('xname')
var input2 = document.getElementsByTagName('text')

submit.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
  getUpdate();
});

function getUpdate() {
  let text;
  if (input1 == "nokia" && input2 == "nokia") {
    text = "nuke"
  } else {
    text = "input nokia in both input"
  }
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text;
}
```

```css
body {
  background-image: url('https://backgroundcheckall.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/12/technology-background-image-11.jpg');
}
```

```html
<h1>Input your text here</h1>
<label for="fname"></label> <input type="text" id="xname" name="fname"> + <label for="lname"></label> <input type="text" id="lname" name="lname"> =
<button>Submit</button>
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Comment: also, input1 is a input element, not it's value, input2 is a collection of `<text>` elements , not a single one, (in this case, it's an empty collection) and definitely not a value of an element

Comment: I want the function to take the 2 inputs I declared , and sees If they both match the string "nokia" , If they do it'll return "nuke" text , otherwise it'll return " try to input nokia in both " then It'll return text and overwrite the <p> element , when I do <onclick> event inside HTML it works but In javascript it doesnt seem to do any response.

Comment: `for="fname"` is that a typo?

Answer (score 1):

Few things:

- You don't have anything with the id `submit`
- You don't have a tag named `text`. You're looking for the element with the id `lname`.

```js
setTimeout(() => {
  alert("hi starquest");
}, 200);

var submit = document.getElementById('submit');
var input1 = document.getElementById('xname')
var input2 = document.getElementById('lname');

submit.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
  getUpdate();
})

function getUpdate() {
  let text;

  if (input1.value == "nokia" && input2.value == "nokia") {
    text = "nuke"
  } else {
    text = "input nokia in both input"
  }
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <style>
    body {
      background-image: url('https://backgroundcheckall.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/12/technology-background-image-11.jpg');
    }
  </style>
  <script src="test.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Input your text here</h1>
  <label for="fname"></label> <input type="text" id="xname" name="fname"> + <label for="lname"></label> <input type="text" id="lname" name="lname"> =
  <button id="submit">Submit</button>
  <p id="demo"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

There are a few issues with your code.

1. `input2` is empty, because there is no element with tagname `text"
2. `submit` variable is undefined, because there is no element with id `submit`
3. you are comparing `input1` which is an element to a string, you want compare it's value instead (the same goes to `input2` once it's properly defined)
4. the result of the condition is reversed when it's true it will show "nuke"

```js
setTimeout(() => {
  alert("hi starquest");
}, 200);

var submit = document.getElementById('submit');
var input1 = document.getElementById('xname')
var input2= document.getElementById('lname')

submit.addEventListener("click", function (event) {
  getUpdate();
})


function getUpdate(){
  let text;

if(input1.value == "nokia" && input2.value == "nokia"){
  text = "input nokia in both input"
} else {
  text = "nuke"
}
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text;
}
```

```html
    <h1>Input your text here</h1>

    <label for="fname"></label> <input type="text" id="xname" name="fname">   +   <label for="lname"></label> <input type="text" id="lname" name="lname">   = 
   
   
    <button id="submit">Submit</button>
    
    <p id="demo"></p>
```

Comment: close: input2 is an empty HTML collection